# GTM triggers based on javascript functions

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have made an app in javascript/jquery... a type of interactive lesson

I want to have a trigger for "Lesson Finished"...

And this only happens when the function lessonFinished() is fired within my javascript

How can I set up a trigger in GTM to detect that a specific function in javascript has been fired... or what is the correct workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use decoration to add functionality to the function. but this will only work if you are using globally accessible functions. You could create a custom HTML event and use something like this.

```
$(function(){
    if( typeof lessonFinished !== 'function'){
        // need to delay the execution
        console.error('lesson finished not defined');
    }
    // save the original lesson finished function
    var originalLessonFinishedFunction = lessonFinished;
    // decorate the lesson finished function with tag manager stuff
    lessonFinished = function(){

        // call the original function
        originalLessonFinishedFunction();

        // do the tag manager data layer push
        dataLayer.push({
            event: 'Lesson Finished',
            timing: Date.now(),
            extra: 'stuff'
        });
    }
});
```